# How do I pass an array of functions as argument if size of array isn't known

Tags: c++, argument-passing

Here's a simple (and a silly one, yeah) example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

void callFunctionsFromAnArray(void *(*)(int), int);
void f1(int);
void f2(int);
void f3(int);

int main()
{
    const int n = 3;
    void (*functions[n]) (int) = { f1, f2, f3 };
    callFunctionsFromAnArray(functions, n);
}

void callFunctionsFromAnArray(void *(*f) (int), int fCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
        f[i](1);
}

void f1(int a)
{
    std::cout << a * 1 << '\n';
}
void f2(int a)
{
    std::cout << a * 2 << '\n';
}
void f3(int a)
{
    std::cout << a * 3 << '\n';
}
```

And those are the errors I'm getting when trying to compile:

```
12:9: error: no matching function for call to 'callFunctionsFromAnArray'
        callFunctionsFromAnArray(functions, n);
3:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (*[3])(int)' to 'void *(*)(int)' for 1st argument
    void callFunctionsFromAnArray(void *(*)(int), int);
17:13: error: subscript of pointer to function type 'void *(int)'
            f[i](1);
2 errors generated.
```

However, if I change argument to be `void (*f[3]) (int)` it works. But the problem is, it's not always possible to know array's size before run-time (that's why function has 2nd argument after all). Is there any solution?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use `typedef` for function types, to help avoid this problem.

Comment: How about a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in this case, the array decays into a pointer, you don't have to know its size beforehand -- inside a function argument declaration, **and only there,** the pointer and the array qualifier (`*` and `[]`) are equivalent, and the size of the array doesn't matter.

As a result, you can declare your function to take an array of 3 (or however many) pointers, and then you can pass it an array of **any** pointers:

```
void callFunctionsFromAnArray(void *(*f[1])(int), int fCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
        f[i](i);
}
```

However, if you don't like this, you can just make it accept a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void callFunctionsFromAnArray(void *(**f)(int), int fCount); // etc.
```

---

However, if this really is C++, you'd be better off passing a const reference to a vector of `std::function`s:

```
void callFunctionsFromAnArray(const std::vector<std::function<void *(int)> > &a)
{
     // call'em
}
```

Comment: +1, although I think it's probably `void (**f) (int)` that's needed, based on the functions being called (I think the OP just misplaced the `*`, essentially).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sounds reasonable. Let's see what OP actually meant. In the meantime, I've added a more C++-esque solution as well.

Comment: is incorrect: "arrays always, unconditionally decay into pointers when passed to a function"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks! What's an exception?

Comment: mostly when the formal argument is a reference. oh okay, thinking about it that's the only exception.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's correct. Amended my answer accordingly. Passionate hate against references increased.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's right, first time doing this, thought '*' shouldn't be in those parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++ and not C, I highly suggest you to use `std::vector` and `std::function` instead. They will make your life much easier, especially in this particular case:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

void f1(int);
void f2(int);
void f3(int);

using function_vector = std::vector<std::function<void(int)>>;

void callFunctions(const function_vector& vec) {
    for (const auto& f : vec)
        f(1);
}

int main() {
    function_vector vec = { &f1, &f2, &f3 };
    callFunctions(vec);
}
```

You can see a live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c56d925d9094310e).

Comment: Please add `const` a few places, so as not to teach Bad Programming Habits(TM).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, sounds about right. For some reasons I thought that `operator()` of `std::function` was not declared `const`.